# Does Ambari restore configuration after a manual change to a config file?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I'm running a Microsoft HDInsight 3.6 cluster with edge node. For our application requirements, we need to change a property value in the core-site.xml on the edge node, which we are currently trying to achieve using a shell script (using sed command)

However, we see that the configuration gets restored to its original value which is causing issues in our application. Note that the edge node host is in the same "default" config group as all the other nodes in the cluster.

I'm new to this so would want to understand the following -

1. Is there a way we can manually edit a file and retain the new config on the edge node?
2. Should we always make a config change via the Ambari server?

I'm new to this so if I have missed any important information needed in support of my question, please comment I'll provide it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ambari will overwrite any changes made to core-site.xml outside of Ambari. In an Ambari managed cluster, you should use "custom core-site" properties to add custom properties to core-site.xml. This can be found via HDFS -> Configs -> Advanced -> Custom Core-Site in Ambari. If you need this to apply to only a specific node only, you can create a config group for your edge node(s).

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonathan! This helped.